# Erro no comando CRUD ATUALIZAR - java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 8

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Estou montando um sistema Java com ligação ao banco MySQL, mas parei em um certo ponto pois não consigo localizar o erro. O meu método atualizar acontece um erro no JUnit, mas não consigo descobrir qual é.

Segue partes do código:

```
package com.sistemacliente.DAO;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.sistemacliente.domain.Balada;
import com.sistemacliente.domain.Cliente;
import com.sistemacliente.factory.ConexaoFactory;

public class ClienteDAO {


    public void salvar(Cliente c) throws SQLException {
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append("INSERT INTO cliente");
        sql.append("(nome,sobrenome,telefone,email,data,valor,baladas_codigo)");
        sql.append("VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

        Connection conexao = ConexaoFactory.conectar();

        PreparedStatement comando = conexao.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
        comando.setString(1, c.getNome());
        comando.setString(2, c.getSobrenome());
        comando.setInt(3, c.getTelefone());
        comando.setString(4, c.getEmail());
        comando.setDate(5, c.getData());
        comando.setDouble(6, c.getValor());
        comando.setInt(7, c.getBalada().getCodigo());

        comando.executeUpdate();

    }

    public ArrayList<Cliente> listar() throws SQLException {

        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append(
                "SELECT c.codigo, c.nome, c.sobrenome, c.telefone, c.email, c.data, c.valor, b.codigo, b.descricao ");
        sql.append("FROM cliente c   ");
        sql.append("INNER JOIN balada b ON b.codigo = c.baladas_codigo");

        Connection conexao = ConexaoFactory.conectar();

        PreparedStatement comando = conexao.prepareStatement(sql.toString());

        ResultSet resultado = comando.executeQuery();

        ArrayList<Cliente> lista = new ArrayList<Cliente>();

        while (resultado.next()) {
            Balada b = new Balada();
            b.setCodigo(resultado.getInt("b.codigo"));
            b.setDescricao(resultado.getString("b.descricao"));

            Cliente c = new Cliente();
            c.setCodigo(resultado.getInt("c.codigo"));
            c.setNome(resultado.getString("c.nome"));
            c.setSobrenome(resultado.getString("c.sobrenome"));
            c.setTelefone(resultado.getInt("c.telefone"));
            c.setEmail(resultado.getString("c.email"));
            c.setData(resultado.getDate("c.data"));
            c.setValor(resultado.getDouble("c.valor"));
            c.setBalada(b);

            lista.add(c);
        }
        return lista;

    }

    public void excluir(Cliente c) throws SQLException {
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append("DELETE FROM cliente ");
        sql.append("WHERE codigo = ?");

        Connection conexao = ConexaoFactory.conectar();

        PreparedStatement comando = conexao.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
        comando.setInt(1, c.getCodigo());
        comando.executeUpdate();

    } 

    public void atualizar(Cliente c) throws SQLException {

        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append("UPDATE cliente");
        sql.append("SET codigo = ? , nome = ? , sobrenome = ? , telefone = ? ,"
                + " email = ? ,  data = ? , valor = ? , baladas_codigo = ? ");
        sql.append("WHERE codigo =  ? ");

        Connection conexao = ConexaoFactory.conectar();

        PreparedStatement comando = conexao.prepareStatement(sql.toString());

        comando.setString(1, c.getNome());
        comando.setString(2, c.getSobrenome());
        comando.setInt(3, c.getTelefone());
        comando.setString(4, c.getEmail());
        comando.setDate(5, c.getData());
        comando.setDouble(6, c.getValor());
        comando.setInt(7, c.getCodigo());

        comando.executeUpdate();

    } 
}
```

E aqui esta a parte do JUnit:

```
    @Test
    public void atualizar() throws SQLException {

        Cliente c = new Cliente();
        c.setCodigo(7);
        c.setNome("Koppa");
        c.setSobrenome("Troppa");
        c.setTelefone(11111);
        c.setEmail("teste@gmail.com");
        c.setData(new Date(2016/07/10));
        c.setValor(5.00);

        Balada b = new Balada();
        b.setCodigo(14);
        c.setBalada(b);

        ClienteDAO dao = new ClienteDAO();
        dao.atualizar(c);

    }
}
```

Eis o erro gerado:

> java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 8

Screenshot do erro:

[image: Erro do JUnit]

Answer (score 2):

1. Não há porque usar o `StringBuilder` para construir uma `String` cada vez que cada método é chamado, sendo que sempre a mesma `String` será construída. Usar uma `String` fixa já pré-fabricada é bem melhor e mais simples.
2. Observe que se alguma exceção for lançada, o `ResultSet`, o `PreparedStatement` e/ou o `Connection` não são fechados em lugar nenhum, e portanto são mantidos abertos, o que pode ocasionar vários problemas. Mesmo se você chamar os métodos `close()` explicitamente, deverá tomar o cuidado de garantir que eles sejam chamados mesmo se a execução for abortada com uma exceção (e daí o uso do `finally` deve ser lembrado). Entretanto, é para esse tipo de situação que a sintaxe *try-with-resources* foi concebida no Java 7.
3. Definir o tipo como sendo `ArrayList<AlgumaCoisa>` não é considerado uma boa prática de programação quando `List<AlgumaCoisa>` for suficiente. A principal razão é que usando `ArrayList<AlgumaCoisa>` (exceto no construtor) significa que você está codificando para uma implementação, enquanto que com `List<AlgumaCoisa>` você está codificando para uma interface. As boas práticas de desenvolvimento de software orientado a objetos dizem que o ideal é codificar-se para uma interface e não para uma implementação.
4. Use a sintaxe do diamante que o Java 7 introduziu para ter que evitar de repetir os tipos genéricos nos construtores.
5. Este código aqui:

   ```
   StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
   sql.append("UPDATE cliente");
   sql.append("SET codigo = ? , nome = ? , sobrenome = ? , telefone = ? ,"
           + " email = ? ,  data = ? , valor = ? , baladas_codigo = ? ");
   sql.append("WHERE codigo =  ? ");
   ```

   Produz a seguinte `String`:

   ```sql
   UPDATE clienteSET codigo = ? , nome = ? , sobrenome = ? , telefone = ? , email = ? ,  data = ? , valor = ? , baladas_codigo = ? WHERE codigo =  ?
   ```

   Esta `String` tem dois problemas. O primeiro problema é que ao usar o `StringBuilder`, você não se atentou aos espaços e acabou produzindo um `clienteSET` tudo junto, o que obviamente dá um erro de sinatxe no SQL.

   O segundo problema é que não faz sentido você colocar o código do cliente duas vezes, vez que o código do cliente informado no `WHERE` (o cliente a ser alterado) é o mesmo informado no `SET`. Você não está tentando alterar o código do cliente aqui, e só faz sentido colocar no `SET` aquilo que você quer alterar. Assim sendo o primeiro `codigo = ?` não deveria estar lá.
6. O código da sua atualização não define todos os campos que deveriam ser definidos. Faltou preencher o campo do código da balada e também faltou o primeiro código do cliente (mas de acordo com o item 5 acima, este não deveria estar na SQL mesmo).

Eis como fica o seu código com estes problemas todos arrumados:

```java
package com.sistemacliente.DAO;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.sistemacliente.domain.Balada;
import com.sistemacliente.domain.Cliente;
import com.sistemacliente.factory.ConexaoFactory;

public class ClienteDAO {

    private static final String SQL_SALVAR = "INSERT INTO cliente (nome, sobrenome, telefone, email, data, valor, baladas_codigo) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    public void salvar(Cliente c) throws SQLException {   
        try (
            Connection conexao = ConexaoFactory.conectar();
            PreparedStatement comando = conexao.prepareStatement(SQL_SALVAR);
        ) {
            comando.setString(1, c.getNome());
            comando.setString(2, c.getSobrenome());
            comando.setInt(3, c.getTelefone());
            comando.setString(4, c.getEmail());
            comando.setDate(5, c.getData());
            comando.setDouble(6, c.getValor());
            comando.setInt(7, c.getBalada().getCodigo());
            comando.executeUpdate();
        }
    }

    private static final String SQL_LISTAR = "SELECT c.codigo, c.nome, c.sobrenome, c.telefone, c.email, c.data, c.valor, b.codigo, b.descricao FROM cliente c INNER JOIN balada b ON b.codigo = c.baladas_codigo";

    public List<Cliente> listar() throws SQLException {
        List<Cliente> lista = new ArrayList<>();

        try (
            Connection conexao = ConexaoFactory.conectar();
            PreparedStatement comando = conexao.prepareStatement(SQL_LISTAR);
            ResultSet resultado = comando.executeQuery();
        ) {
            while (resultado.next()) {
                Balada b = new Balada();
                b.setCodigo(resultado.getInt("b.codigo"));
                b.setDescricao(resultado.getString("b.descricao"));

                Cliente c = new Cliente();
                c.setCodigo(resultado.getInt("c.codigo"));
                c.setNome(resultado.getString("c.nome"));
                c.setSobrenome(resultado.getString("c.sobrenome"));
                c.setTelefone(resultado.getInt("c.telefone"));
                c.setEmail(resultado.getString("c.email"));
                c.setData(resultado.getDate("c.data"));
                c.setValor(resultado.getDouble("c.valor"));
                c.setBalada(b);

                lista.add(c);
            }
        }
        return lista;
    }

    private static final String SQL_EXCLUIR = "DELETE FROM cliente WHERE codigo = ?";

    public void excluir(Cliente c) throws SQLException {
        try (
            Connection conexao = ConexaoFactory.conectar();
            PreparedStatement comando = conexao.prepareStatement(SQL_EXCLUIR);
        ) {
            comando.setInt(1, c.getCodigo());
            comando.executeUpdate();
        }
    }

    private static final String SQL_ATUALIZAR = "UPDATE cliente SET nome = ?, sobrenome = ?, telefone = ?, email = ?, data = ?, valor = ?, baladas_codigo = ? WHERE codigo = ?";

    public void atualizar(Cliente c) throws SQLException {
        try (
            Connection conexao = ConexaoFactory.conectar();
            PreparedStatement comando = conexao.prepareStatement(SQL_ATUALIZAR);
        ) {
            comando.setString(1, c.getNome());
            comando.setString(2, c.getSobrenome());
            comando.setInt(3, c.getTelefone());
            comando.setString(4, c.getEmail());
            comando.setDate(5, c.getData());
            comando.setDouble(6, c.getValor());
            comando.setInt(7, c.getBalada().getCodigo());
            comando.setInt(8, c.getCodigo());
            comando.executeUpdate();
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom, faz tempo que não programo em java, mas acredito que seu erro esta aqui:

```
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append("UPDATE cliente");
    sql.append("SET codigo = ? , nome = ? , sobrenome = ? , telefone = ? ,"
            + " email = ? ,  data = ? , valor = ? , baladas_codigo = ? ");
    sql.append("WHERE codigo =  ? ");
```

Primeiro ponto, que não é recomendado atualizar o código quando ele for a chave primaria e principalmente quando ele esta na condição `WHERE`. E repare que voce passou 9 vezes o `?`, então ele vai esperar que você passe 9 valores posteriormente o que no caso voce não fez. Você colocou apenas 7, faltando o `baladas_codigo`:

```
    comando.setString(1, c.getNome());
    comando.setString(2, c.getSobrenome());
    comando.setInt(3, c.getTelefone());
    comando.setString(4, c.getEmail());
    comando.setDate(5, c.getData());
    comando.setDouble(6, c.getValor());
    comando.setInt(7, c.getCodigo());
```

O correto seria algo proximo disso:

```
 public void atualizar(Cliente c) throws SQLException {

    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append("UPDATE cliente");
    sql.append("SET nome = ? , sobrenome = ? , telefone = ? ,"
            + " email = ? ,  data = ? , valor = ? , baladas_codigo = ? ");
    sql.append("WHERE codigo =  ? ");

    Connection conexao = ConexaoFactory.conectar();

    PreparedStatement comando = conexao.prepareStatement(sql.toString());

    comando.setString(1, c.getNome());
    comando.setString(2, c.getSobrenome());
    comando.setInt(3, c.getTelefone());
    comando.setString(4, c.getEmail());
    comando.setDate(5, c.getData());
    comando.setDouble(6, c.getValor());
    comando.setDouble(7, c.getBaladas_codigo());// Aqui é só um exemplo, poi pelo que vi, esta em outra tabela, ou você retira do SQL ou passa de alguma forma

    comando.setInt(8, c.getCodigo());

    comando.executeUpdate();

}
```

Acredito que seja o erro que esta acontecendo. Qualquer coisa comenta aqui, se não consegui explicar bem!

Comment: Sem contar que é desnecessário criar um StringBuilder para construir a query e depois converter para String. Mais fácil fazer uma query direto em string

Comment: Então...  Ficaria até mais simples e legível